# RuntimeWarning while importing scipy.stats

Tags: scipy, anaconda, python-3.7

While importing the scipy.stats I got following error, how to resolve this error
my versions are:
'3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]'
Anaconda version: 2019.03 Build: py37_0

```
import scipy.stats as stats
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-7e938f6e949f>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.stats as stats

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 367, in <module>
    from .stats import *

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 172, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *

  File "__init__.pxd", line 918, in init scipy.special._ufuncs

RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. 
Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject
```

Comment: How did you install scipy and numpy?